How to connect Chrome extension to a Database?
I am trying to create a simple Chrome Extension, and want to connect it to a realtime database. I tried connecting it to Firebase, but I simply can not get it working.
I dont plan on storing any sensitive data. So far I have created the standard Chrome extension files, popup.html, popup.js, background.js, manifest.json.
I do not want to store the data locally, since all users should be able to see the stored data.
Any ideas on how to connect a chrome extension to a realtime database? Firebase?

You said you tried to connect it to Firebase but what exactly have you tried?

Firebase documentation should have an example for chrome extensions or you can find it by googling, I vaguely remember it being mentioned in https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions
